# How to expand, hide pickerView by touching button? Swift

Tags: swift, uipickerview

unfortunately I couldn't find this basic answer on the internet. I want to make a function that whenever I touch the button, the pickerView shows up/hides

Answer (score 0):

Hook the pickerView with a height constraint and do this to show/Hide

```
func showPicker(_ show:Bool) {

    self.pickHeight.constant = show ? 200 : 0

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

}
```